# How can I configure Plastic SCM Cloud to store Jet databases on another drive?

Tags: windows, jet, plasticscm

By default, Plastic SCM puts local repositories under Program Files. In a situation where the C drive is a small SSD, and there is a secondary (let's assume D) drive that is larger, what do I need to do in order to move existing repositories to and/or establish new repositories on the D drive?

Comment: This question is about the Cloud edition in particular, however if the steps are the same for the standard edition, or if someone is able to provide an answer that covers _both_ editions, then I will update the title of this question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create (if you don't have it yet) a "jet.conf" file inside the Plastic SCM server directory (typically "C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\server" on windows) and set the "basepath" value to the path location where you want to store the jet database files. Let me give you an example:

jet.conf:

```
basepath=D:\jetdbs
```

You can also configure the following extra parameters:

```
**prefix**: prefix to be added to the db files
**suffix**: Suffix to be added to the db files
**maxcachedtrees**: Max value of trees (changeset strucure) to be cached in RAM.
**datafilesize**: Used to split the blob file (where the revisions content are stored) in pieces based on the size you set here (GB).
```

(detailed info can be found at the official doc: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#ConfigurePlasticSCMwithJet)